# Python throwing error FileNotFound instead of just creating file

Tags: python, file, error-handling, directory, python-3.9

I am working on a python program that will later be ran in command_line that creates new directories for you and adds python file to directory. I have that part down pretty well I think, but my question is how to make this python program create python file in same directory when no name is given for new directory. I keep getting an error which is as follows:
***FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''***

[CODE:]

```
import os

folder = input('Folder Name: ')
file = input('File Name: ')

if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.mkdir(folder)
    with open(folder + '/' + file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass
else: 
    with open(folder + '/' + file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass
    
if folder == '':
    with open(file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to create a folder even if you get an empty string, so you have to add an additional condition to skip making the folder.

```
import os

folder = input('Folder Name: ')
file = input('File Name: ')

# check if folder is valid and doesn't exist
if folder and not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.mkdir(folder)
    with open(folder + '/' + file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass
else: 
    with open(folder + '/' + file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass

# if folder is either '' or None...
if not folder:
    with open(file + '.py', 'w') as newfile:
        pass
```

And a more simplified version of your logic...

```
import os

folder = input('Folder Name: ')
file = input('File Name: ')

# check if folder is valid and doesn't exist
if folder and not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.mkdir(folder)

py_file = f"{file}.py"
file_path = f"{folder}/{py_file}" if folder else py_file

# since you're just creating an empty file, can just
# use open and close rather than a with statement
open(file_path, "w").close()
```

Or using [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if you're on any remotely new version of Python 3.

```
import pathlib

folder = input('Folder Name: ')
file = input('File Name: ')

directory = pathlib.Path(folder)

# basically like mkdir -p, and it's okay if the directory
# already exists
directory.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

py_file = directory / f"{file}.py"
py_file.touch()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this does:

py_file = f"{file}.py"
file_path = f"{folder}/{py_file}" if folder else py_file

..aside from declaring variables and I'm never heard of PathLib module, but I'm still fairly new to python even though I did a pro class on code academy.

Could you elaborate a bit more on the variables you declared please

Comment: @LeeIsII If you're new to Python, don't worry too much about my more condensed answers, but check: [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for the `f"{file}.py"` string formatting. See [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) for the `a if b else c` style syntax I used (it's basically a ternary operator). `pathlib` is just a more specific library in Python for dealing with the filesystem, rather than calling a bunch of `os` methods.